# How to uncompress two rar archives preserve content order?

Tags: debian, directory-structure, archive

How to uncompress two rar archives preserve content order? The archives is not .part1,.part2, just two separate archives containing video courses in folders. The folder names in first and second archive partially overlap each other. I need merge archives content into one folder with lesson subfolders. Separate extraction gives an error, and part of extracted folders are empty.  [Linux Debian, xarchiver].

Comment: Check out `unar`.  There's a lot of directory specific options.